# Timeouts associating Wifi interface with a specific AP

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, broadcom

**By now, the problem stated here has not been solved but it has gone away. I am using a different interface that works fine.**

Perhaps this is a question for another Stackexchange forum, but since this is on Linux, I try here.

My goal is to turn an HP t520 thin client into a Kodi box. I need the Wifi interface.

**My problem**: The Broadcom 43228 interface built into the box doesn't associate with the 2.4GHz access point. A connection with the 5GHz AP can be established but is so bad (three digit millisecond delays) that it's unusable.

This happens when I use the newest Libreelec, Antix and Ubuntu. However, Debian 11 and Alpine work. Ubuntu (have not yet tried the others) also has no problem with a cheap USB interface based on Realtek 8188.

**How can I better understand where/why this is failing**? Is there a way to trace what happens?

I use `wpa_cli` to test it. `wpa_supplicant` is running in the background as a systemd service on Debian, Ubuntu and Libreelec `/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant`, and a native service on Antix and Alpine. Adding -ddd options has not provided relevant information.

**On Debian:**

```
$ sudo modinfo wl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.0-9-amd64/updates/dkms/wl.ko
...
$ sudo wpa_cli
...
> enable_network 0
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
>
>
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Trying to associate with e4:7e:66:48:e1:6c (SSID='bureau-2.4G' freq=2447 MHz)
<3>Associated with e4:7e:66:48:e1:6c
```

**On Ubuntu:**

```
$ sudo modinfo wl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
...
$ sudo wpa_cli
...
> enable_network 0
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
> status
wpa_state=SCANNING
address=54:8c:a0:07:40:49
uuid=580670db-2bf6-52fc-b453-147c9671e770
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Trying to associate with e4:7e:66:48:e1:6c (SSID='bureau-2.4G' freq=2457 MHz)
>
>
<3>Authentication with e4:7e:66:48:e1:6c timed out.
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e4:7e:66:48:e1:6c reason=3 locally_generated=1
```

The obvious solution would be to forget about Broadcom and use a USB interface. This irks me, however (I don't want to spend another 5$ after purchasing the t520 for 20$). Trying to run Kodi on Debian and Alpine turned out to be another nightmare.

Comment: Could you add to your post your Ubuntu version, wpa_supplicant conf, and AP model? Also, run `iwevent` in another terminal window on the client while the authentication fails, it might give more verbose output. The fastest way to see what is going wrong would be to check the logs on your AP to see if it is getting the authentication requests, and why it might be rejecting them.

Comment: Also a friendly word of caution - you should use the `-i` option when using `wpa_cli`. If your adapter supports `p2p` connections, `wpa_suppilcant` will bring up two interfaces, one regular interface named (for example) `wlp1s0`, then one whose name is prepended with an additional string `p2p-wlp1s0`. 'p' comes before 'w' lexicographically. When you run `wpa_cli` with no options, it chooses the `p2p` interface by default. So it's better to write out `wpa_cli -i <iface>`

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have since moved on and exchanged the WiFi interface with the interface of an old laptop that I had lying around. It was the most recent Ubuntu version, but it's hard to go back and test it again. Thanks also for the -i option; I did use it occasionally, but not consistently. Unfortunately the AP in question is an all-in-one device (fibre-optic modem, router and AP) with poor documentation and little in terms of troubleshooting tools. I can't even change its log level. Another AP that I have lying around has no problems connecting.

Comment: I added a paragraph stating that the problem is gone. Sorry for wasting your time.